# I'm trying to use NSTimer in a tableview with mutliple timers

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

When I start a timer, however, it seems to repeatedly run, but it won't decrease the counter. I'm trying to pass the count variable through the counter into the selector, but it seems that the counter resets each time, instead of continuely decreasing. I'm new to programming, so while I'm hoping it's something silly, I might have everything wrong organizationally... my code is:

```
func timerDidEnd(timer: NSTimer) {

var timeCount = timer.userInfo as! Double

timeCount -= timeInterval

if timeCount <= 0 {  //test for target time reached.
    print("Timer = 0")
    timer.invalidate()
} else { //update the time on the clock if not reached
    print("Timer Count: \(timeCount)")
}


extension ViewController: TimerTableViewCellDelegate {

func startTimer(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    print("timer \(indexPath.row) button started")

    var currentTimer = baseArray[indexPath.row]

    currentTimer.timeCount = Double((currentTimer.duration[0] * 60) + (currentTimer.duration[1]) + currentTimer.duration[2])

    currentTimer.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: "timerDidEnd:", userInfo: currentTimer.timeCount, repeats: true)

}

func stopTimer(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let currentTimer = baseArray[indexPath.row]

    print("Stop Timer")
    currentTimer.timer.invalidate()

}
```

Comment: The variable `timeCount` creates a copy of the value stored in `timer.userInfo`. So it does not change `timer.userInfo` to a new value.

Comment: Using invalidate stops the timer and never runs it again. Removing timer.invalidate from timerDidEnd should keep your timer running. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate

Comment: Thanks @Mats - If this is the case, is there a way to update the counter another way? I've tried getting the indexPath via userInfo to then pull the correct timeCount, but it seems that when I try this the timeCount resets back to 0, instead of keeping the type I assigned it in the 'startTimer' function

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- I updated my timer struct to include the proper time count, and this worked while passing in the indexPath as userInfo